# Buying non-Kosher food for home Emergency Kits

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

The [United States federal government](http://www.ready.gov/build-a-kit), [American Red Cross](http://www.redcross.org/prepare/location/home-family/get-kit), and surely countless other governments and NGOs recommend that families have Emergency Survival Kits in their homes in case of a natural or manmade disaster, equipped with many different kinds of supplies, including a two-week to one-month (in some cases longer) supply of non-perishable food.

In an emergency, of course, one is permitted to eat whatever is available and can support survival.  But what about actively preparing for such an emergency by building a survival kit equipped with non-Kosher food?  Does it make a difference if the non-Kosher food one can purchase has a longer shelf-life than what one can purchase or prepare that is Kosher?  Is one allowed to disregard a Kosher item that is available that is simply unpleasant and unpalatable?  Does it matter if the cost of Kosher food fit for an emergency kit is cost-prohibitive?

Comment: "Is one allowed to disregard a Kosher item that is available that is simply unpleasant and unpalatable?" I can't imagine why that would be a consideration, unless it's so bad you wouldn't be able to ingest it.

Comment: @DoubleAA, [Ahem](http://myrightword.blogspot.com/2010/07/oiy-vey-theyve-canned-cholent.html) ([Photo](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_ITWI9nTWaek/TDb5s1hfarI/AAAAAAAANEM/PYFZRgqPCAE/s1600/ch.jpg))

Comment: @SethJ, what: the tschölent or that it's canned?

Comment: אין מפליגין בספינה (שבת יט:) וע"ע בעל המאור (שם או לקמן פרק ר' אליעזר דמילה)

Comment: Reminds me of the question of entering medical school (or seeking employment as a doctor), knowing one will have to work on _Shabas_ to save a life. I'm not saying the two are halachically similar (I don't know), just that they seem similar to me.

Comment: I'm curious if the downvote was because the voter felt this wasn't a quality question or because it was offensive.

Comment: `Remember any special dietary needs.` -- From one of the question's [links](http://www.ready.gov/food).

Comment: No in the case of cost prohibition the poor are allowed to break Shabbat and kosher laws. It's unethical and therefore ungodly to burden poor or middle class people with kashrut in the case of emergency preparation.

Comment: @user2566 that’s not how Jewish law works. God and his Torah determine what is ethical and Godly.

Comment: I would speculate it is permitted since there is only the slightest chance of needing to use these foods. We are not required to prepare religiously for remote contingencies. For example, one doesn’t need to leave five hours to get home from work on Friday, nor carry 3 days worth of Kosher food when running an errand. The Mesillas Yesharim specifically cautions against worrying too much about things that might possibly happen. (Zehirus)

Comment: one should be aware that many foods like hardtack are Chametz and may not be owned on Pesach, kosher or not (if you keep your kit over multiple years)

Comment: @LN6595, would your interpretation of M"Y not also prohibit this? If it's unwise to prepare for such emergencies, wouldn't it then be inappropriate to prepare *with* things that are normally prohibited?

Answer (score 4):

The Gemara says in Shabbos ([19a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=19&format=pdf))

> ת"ר אין מפליגין בספינה פחות מג' ימים קודם לשבת
>   The rabbis taught: one may not travel by boat less than three days before Shabbos.

( *translation mine* )

The Rishonim discuss why this is not allowed. The [Ba'al HaMaor](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99) on that Gemara (7a in דפי הרי"ף*) writes that the reason is because he is putting himself into a dangerous position, where he would have to violate Shabbos to preserve his life, and one is not allowed to do that *ab initio*.

I would suggest that this case (of buying non-kosher food) is analogous to that case (of sailing too close to Shabbos), because in both of them, one is placing himself in a dangerous position where he will have to break הלכה in order to save his life -- something that he is definitely allowed to do, but still should not plan on doing so [*lechatchila*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323).

[CYLOR](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/594/5323) ( *I haven't, but I have the feeling that he would ask me exactly how much more expensive it is to do it kosher, and I would end up buying kosher* :P )

---

*<sub>link appreciated!</sub>

Comment: This is from memory, as I do not currently have access to my notes on Shabbos. I decided to post anyway, because I was able to find the Gemara and the Ba'al HaMaor. However, it should be noted that this is not as simple as I laid it out, because other Rishonim disagree with the Ba'al HaMaor on the reasoning for this Gemara, and because there is another Gemara (ibid. 134b) that discusses a similar situation, and there may or may not be a contradiction in the Ba'al HaMaor that has to be dealt with. [.......]

Comment: [.......] I posted this so others will have something to think about, and when I am able to, I will (God-willing) fill in the rest of the info.

Comment: It might make a difference if the only shelf-stable food available wasn't kosher (or at least, didn't have  a hechsher).  Fortunately, at least in North America and Israel, that is not the case.  There is a huge variety of shelf-stable canned and vacuum-packed foods that are certified kosher.  These foods can be found in any standard supermarket.  If a Jew lives in Estonia, tzarich iyun.

Comment: @Jake what if the Jew lives in Wyoming?

Comment: @SethJ  Many U.S. national brands have kosher certification.  His emergency kit can include vegetarian baked beans, a wide assortment of canned fruits and vegetables, tuna fish cans, powdered milk and special boxed milk that doesn't spoil (if one holds chalav stam, but I mean c'mon, it's Wyoming).  It's quite easy to buy national brands at any grocery store in the USA and only eat kosher certified food.

Comment: @Jake say he has an iron deficiency. He needs meat. Then what? My local kosher supermarket carries shelf-stable, boxed, self-heating meat meals. What's the guy in Wyoming supposed to do?

Comment: @SethJ iron supplements are much more shelf-stable than any food product.  In any case, tzarich iyun / CYLOR

Comment: @Jake iron supplements don't work nice idea though

Comment: @Jake aside from what caseyr547 states (for which a proof would be nice), mightn't it matter that this is preparation in the event of a disaster, in which case one might want to preserve the supplements for when the iron-rich food runs out (or perhaps they are taken *in addition* to an iron-rich diet)?

Comment: @SethJ http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20992/why-cant-you-just-take-a-vitamin-why-you-need-a-healthy-diet-on-top-of-that/21003?noredirect=1#comment32930_21003

Comment: @Jake I think a large percentage of the Jews in Wyoming do not eat chalav stam (Chabad)

Comment: @Jake, what about controversial Hechsherim, especially for meat - ala Hebrew National or others? I imagine a dried HN salami might last quite a while.

Comment: @Jake, also, more than likely, the Chabad Shaliah to Wyoming cares about Halav Stam.